# DataGridTemplateColumn for different sources

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my application I have a `Window` with three `DataGrid`s on it. All `DataGrid`s should have the same colums.

Two of the `DataGrid`s are bound to an `ObservableCollection<DisplayItem>`. The third `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<GeneralItem>`.

The class `GeneralItem` has a property of type `DisplayItem`.

The definition of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` for the Item-Name in two of three `DataGrid`s looks like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Item-Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" 
                   Text="{Binding Module.DisplayItem.Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The definition of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` for the Item-Name in the third `DataGrid` looks like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Item-Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" 
                   Text="{Binding Module.GeneralItem.DisplayItem.Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I know that I can make `DataGridTemplateColumn`s to resources and use it as `StaticResource`s.

What I now want to know: Is there a possibility that I only have to write the `DataGridTemplateColumn` once and it can handle both situations? For example by providing a DataContext to the StaticResource or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template selector to allow you to choose which template to use.

```
<Window.Resource>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" 
                   Text="{Binding Module.DisplayItem.Text}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" 
                   Text="{Binding Module.GeneralItem.DisplayItem.Text}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resource>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item-Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        <local:DisplayItemTemplateSelector
            FirstTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}"
            SecondTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}"/>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

public class DisplayItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate FirstTemplate
  { get; set; }

  public DataTemplate SecondTemplate
  { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {

    if (item is  GeneralItem)
    {
        //second template etc
    }
    else if (item is DisplayItem)
    {
        //first template
    }
    else
      return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
  }
}
```